# how to use a %let macro inside of a hash table in SAS

Tags: hash, sas, hashtable, sas-macro

I'm updating a program that uses Hash tables. And the program has a lot of repeated variables that are changed on a regular basis.
I've been updating them to reference a program containing macro code for these variables so we don't have to change them one by one, and it's been working like a charm in all my other projects, but I'm struggling with these hash tables
eg

```
%let year = x2020;
data acute &year.;
  if 0 then set a_&syear.;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare has Tx(dataset:"Ty");
    Tx.defineData("city","&year.");
    Tx.define();
    call missing(city,&year.);
  end;
....
run;
```

I've narrowed it down to the use of &year. in the Tx.defineData line.
It doesn't seem to be picking the macro inside the quotations, and am given this error:

> undeclared data symbol &year. for has object

though I usually don't have issues with macros inside quotes.
I've tried changing the let function to `%let year = "x2020";` and using `dequote()` for areas that don't need the quotations, I've also tried using `quote(&year.)` instead but get

> undeclared data symbol"   ." for hash object....

Has anyone worked out a way to use a let macro in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

## Your main problem is,

you are trying to use names of datasets and fields that start with a digit. Names in SAS should start with a letter or an underscore and contain only letters, underscores and digits. If not, they should be written differently.

- Write `"name with blanks"n` to create a variable or dataset named `name with blanks`
- Write `"1_2_3"n` to create a variable or dataset named `name with blanks`

Now that works, but I advice you not to do so, because the syntax becomes quite complex.

## Your code is incomplete and contains a lot of typo's.

Therefore, I have to guess what you actually wanted to do.
It would help if you cut and paste it for us, or better, cut and paste the log, so we know exactly what you did.

## The data step

I assume with `data acute &year.;`, you only wanted to create one dataset, named `acute 2020`. If so, you should have written `data "acute &year."n;`, but I actually advice you to rename your dataset and write `data acute_&year.;`.

You might also have wanted to create datasets `acute` and `2020` in one datastep. Then you should have written `data acute "&year"n.;`

## The declaration of the hash table

First, it is not `declare has`, but `declare hash` and not `Tx.define();` but `Tx.defineDONE();`.

If with `Tx.defineData("city","&year.");` you wanted to specifies the fields `city` and `2020` should be used as data, that should work, because here you specify variable names as strings, not as SAS names.

The error is actually in `call missing(city,&year.);` Here you should use the special syntax `call missing(city,"&year."n);`

Again, I advice you to rename your variable, for instance to _2020, so you can just write it as `_&year.`

Comment: sorry, I work of a secure network, so i had to paraphase the code and copy it manually. the variable doesn't actually start with a number, i'll edit that now to your suggest _2020. This code was inherited but i've tried the call missing line with and without the macro, it doesnt have an issue either way, but i tried your suggestion anyway and it still wont work.